# How to set timeout for Net::HTTP.start?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im having trouble where the host that im trying to connect to isn't always avaible. 
Im using this bit of code where im connecting to the host:

```
begin #To catch error from Net::HTTP
net = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
net.read_timeout = 5
net.continue_timeout = 5
res = net.start {|http|
    http_request = http.request(req)
    case http_request.response 
        case
            ...
        else
            @error_msg = "Response not handled by appliaction" << http_request.code << " " << http_request.message 
    end 
}
rescue SocketError => se 
    @error_msg = "Net::SocketError #{se} (Perhaps host is down?)"
    puts @error_msg
end
```

The problem is when the host isnt responding (or something else is wrong) the connection seem to be running way to long. i was hoping for a 5 second wait, 
but its trying for way to long:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 126302ms
Errno::ETIMEDOUT - Connection timed out - connect(2):
```

How do i set the maximum timeout for a Net:HTTP object?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ascar pointed out, this is wrong syntax. 
But :read_timeout alone doesnt fix the issue, I also needed to add :open_timeout if the host didnt respond at all.

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, {read_timeout: 5, open_timeout: 5})
```

Comment: Doesn't work with Net::SSH I get `ArgumentError (invalid option(s): read_timeout, opentimeout)` with ruby 2.3.3, net-ssh (4.2.0, 4.1.0, 4.0.1)

Comment: it has to be `open_timeout`

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is the supported method up to `ruby 1.8`

For `ruby > 1.9` you should use it as a start option.

Try this:

```
res = net.start(:read_timeout => 5) { |http| # your block }
```

See [Net:HTTP.start](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-start)